# Web parse a forum to get text by python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

i have used below code a parse web forum but i am not getting text part in web page. Could you please let me know the error?

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

values={'t':'502286'}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
url='https://www.xossip.com/showthread.php?t='+data
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0(X11; Linux i86)"
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

resp_data = resp.read()
print(resp_data)
```

Comment: What is your desired output? I'm getting the HTML source of the page when I run your code. Also why don't you use beautiful soup when you include it?

Comment: i want the text in web page added by users

Comment: Also might want to give a heads up to people that you're trying to pull from an adult website.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you just do it this way.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('https://www.xossip.com/showthread.php?t=502286').text
```